# Indy "Could not load SSL Library" with Delphi 2007/Apache

Tags: delphi, apache, ssl, indy

I know this question has been asked a number of times.  I seem to have a bit of a different problem.  In my situation after the exception is thrown initially it works fine (and no; I did not turn off exceptions).  So what I have done is on the exception I simply repost:

IdHTTP1.Post(.......

I have put the libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll both in the Apache bin directory and the directory where my ISAPI dll resides.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Indy you need a special build of OpenSSL libraries. The default OpenSSL libraries are not suitable for using with Indy.

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213084/ssl-issues-with-intraweb-delphi-2007). May be you need to try different versions, until you'll find a suitable one.

Comment: That only applies to older versions of Indy.  Modern version use the default OpenSSL DLLs as-is now.

Answer (score 4):

That error means that the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.PassThrough` property is being set to `False` (which would happen when posting to an HTTPS URL) before `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Init()` has been called to intialize the SSL context first.

Sounds like a bug. Next time you get the error, can you grab the stack trace?

Comment: Here it is.  Sorry, I can't seem to insert carriage returns.

:7761b08e kernel32.RaiseException + 0x58

:0113bb57 Call_HookedRaise + $B3

:011f7bed TIdSSLContext.Create + $61

:011f7481 TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Init + $1D

:011f7270 TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.ConnectClient + $20

:012076e2 TIdCustomHTTP.CheckAndConnect + $7E

:01207b2a TIdCustomHTTP.ConnectToHost + $3BE

:01209426 TIdCustomHTTP.DoRequest + $152

:012064d7 TIdCustomHTTP.Post + $9F

:01206899 TIdCustomHTTP.Post + $D1

:012069ec TIdCustomHTTP.Post + $6C

MyMain.SubmitIt

Comment: Given that stack trace, there are a couple of possibilities: 1) the OpenSSL DLLs can't be loaded at all (you can use WhichFailedToLoad() to check that); 2) OpenSSL is loaded but the mi_SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms() function is failing.